# (Kallenberg) Difference Between $\sigma$-finite and locally finite measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

In *Foundations of Modern Probability, 3rd Edition* and *Random Measures, Theory and Applications* by Olav Kallenberg, we get the following defintions:

- A nonempty class $\mathcal U$ of subsets of $S$ is a **ring** if it is closed under finite unions and intersections, as well as under proper differences.
- Given a measurable space $(S,\mathcal S)$, a class $\hat{\mathcal S}\subseteq\mathcal S$ is a **localizing ring** if $\hat{\mathcal S}$ is a subring of $\mathcal S$; $B\in\hat{\mathcal S}$ and $C\in\mathcal S$ implies $B\cap C\in\hat{\mathcal S}$; and $\hat{\mathcal S}=\cup_n(\mathcal S\cap S_n)$ for some sets $S_1,S_2,\ldots\in\hat{\mathcal S}$ satisfying $S_n\uparrow S$. (Here $\mathcal S\cap S_n=\{S\cap S_n:S\in\mathcal S\}$.)
- A measure $\mu$ on a localized measurable space $(S,\mathcal S,\hat{\mathcal S})$ is said to be **locally finite** if $\mu B<\infty$ for every $B\in\hat{\mathcal S}$. (Note that this is different from the usual definition.)

I don't understand the reason for the definition of locally finite measures. How is it different from a $\sigma$-finite measure? If I understand correctly, any locally finite measure (using this definition) is $\sigma$-finite: Given a locally finite $\mu$ on a localized space $(S,\mathcal S,\hat{\mathcal S})$, we can take some $S_1\subseteq S_2\subseteq \cdots\in\hat{\mathcal S}$ such that $S_n\uparrow S$, and then see that $S=\sqcup_n T_n$ where $T_n=S_n\setminus\cup_{j=1}^{n-1}S_j$ and $\mu T_n<\infty$. On the other hand, given a $\sigma$-finite measure space $(S,\mathcal S,\mu)$, we can split $S=\sqcup_n T_n$ with $\mu T_n<\infty$ and define $S_n=\cup_{j=1}^n T_j$ to get a localizing ring $\hat{\mathcal S}=\cup_n(\mathcal S\cap S_n)$. Am I missing something? If not, what is the advantage of defining both $\sigma$-finite and locally finite measures?

Comment: I don’t have the book you referenced, but based on what you wrote down, it seems locally finite applies to a quadruple $(S, \mathcal{S}, \hat{\mathcal{S}}, \mu)$, that is, it is a property not just of the measure but of the measure together with localizing ring. Perhaps the author intended to apply this to specific localizing rings instead of just saying there exists a localizing ring that makes the measure locally finite, which, as you correctly observed, just means it’s $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: Usually locally finite measures are defined for topological spaces equipped with a Borel measure. A Borel measure is locally finite in this definition if every point has an open neighborhood which has finite measure. If the space is a locally compact Hausdorff space, then this is the same as saying the measure of any compact subset is finite. Perhaps the author intended to apply this definition to $\sigma$-compact locally compact Hausdorff spaces? In that case you can choose the localizing ring generated by compact sets, then the two definitions match.

Comment: @DavidGao I think your first comment is probably the right interpretation. As for your second comment, Kallenberg does provide an example of taking $\hat{\mathcal S}$ to consist of the relatively compact sets when $(S,\mathcal S)$ is a locally compact second-countable Hausdorff space equipped with the Borel $\sigma$-field.

Comment: It’s likely that the topological situation is the main case this will apply, given that the author acknowledged that their definition is different from the usual definition and that the usual definition involves topological spaces. Perhaps the author intended to provide a definition of local finiteness that makes sense in a more abstract measure-theoretic setting that generalizes the most common topological setting.